# MySQL "source" command overwrites table

Tags: mysql, import

I have a MySQL Server which has one database called "Backup".
It only has one table with the name "storage".

In the Backup db the storage table contains about 5 Millions datarows.

Now I wanted to append new rows to the table by using the "source" command in the SQL command line.

So what happend is, that source uploaded all the new files in the table, but it overwrote the existing entries (seems that he first deleted all data)

What I have to say is that the sql file that I want to update comes from another server where this table has the same name and structure as "storage".

What I want is to append the new entries that are in the sql file to the one in my datebase. I do not want to overwrite them.

The structure in the two tables is exactly the same. I use the Backup datebase as the name says for backup uses, so that from time to time I can backup my data.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the `.sql` file you're reading with the `SOURCE` command, and remove the `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements that appear there. They are the cause of your table being overwritten; what's actually happening is that the table is being replaced.

You could also look into using `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE` as a faster and less potentially destructive way to get data from one server to the other in a file.

Comment: Thank you! I tried both ways and the second one is much faster.